# I have a code below - works great in IE and Opera, but does not work at all in Firefox / Netscape. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to code below - works great in IE and Opera, but does not work
at all in Firefox / Netscape. Any ideas?

The problem is that nothing happens when clicking printer friendly.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function onPrint()
    {
    window.printForm.submit();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="printForm" action="/xasp?print=on" method="post">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="show" onClick="formSubmit();"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uh, aren't you supposed to close your head before starting on your body?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get form by id, not by name.

```
document.getElementById("printForm").submit();
```

Comment: I revived the original form name from the OP's post.  As x2 has noted though, you would still need to update your form to include an ID.  Alternatively you can keep the name only, and access it by: window.forms['printForm'].submit();

Answer (score 1):

```
document.forms["printForm"].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="printForm" ction="/xasp?print=on" method=post>
```

"ction", what is that? ;) Is this a post typo, or have you misspelled action in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
document.getElementById("printForm").submit();
```

Referencing the form directly from the window object is not standard, well certainly not supported across all browsers.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use document.printForm instead of window.printForm. And in the form tag write "action" not "ction".

Comment: @HollyStyles: W3Schools isn't a good place to find out about standards.

Comment: @mck89: They aren't mutually exclusive choices. document.forms.printForm is fine. http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html

Comment: But a lot of important javascript frameworks use non standard methods, so you won't use them because they're non standard? I don't think so, i think that if they work the are standard(for me)

Comment: @mck89: I know what you mean. But I would always maintain document.GetElementById("id") is best if not using a framework. What I should have said is: 'Not a good standard' my bad.